# Is it possible to count the number of arithmetic operations in R?

Tags: r, arithmetic-expressions

It is possible to record the time that was used to run some code using `system.time`. Here is a little example:

```
system.time(
  mean(rnorm(10^6))
  )
```

But I am not only interested in the time but also in the number of arithmetic operations (that is +,-,*,/) that were used for the code.

In the above-mentioned case it would be easy to count the number of summations and the division in order to get the mean, but the code I would like to apply this to is far more complex.

Therefore, my question is: is there a function in R that counts the number of arithmetic operations?

Comment: At the R level or also at the compiled level (Fortran, C/C++)?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Personally I'd prefer the R level as I am not familiar with Fortran and C. But perhaps it'll be nice for others if you could share your solution.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can trace the R functions of interest:

```
counter <- 0 

trace("+", at = 1, print = FALSE,
      tracer = quote(.GlobalEnv$counter <- .GlobalEnv$counter + 1))
#Tracing function "+" in package "base"
#[1] "+"

Reduce("+", 1:10)
#[1] 55

counter
#[1] 9

untrace("+")
#Untracing function "+" in package "base"
```

I'm not sure how useful it would be to count R level calls here. Many (most?) functions do arithmetic in C or Fortran code or even the BLAS. And I don't have a solution for counting calls in compiled code. You'd need to set that up during compilation if it is possible at all.

Comment: Thanks so much for your solution! Is it also possible to use this for example for a linear model? For example to count the arithmetic operations of `lm(mpg~disp, data = mtcars)`?

Comment: The last paragraph of my answer applies to `lm`.